# unable to call WSDL/SOAP API from Web. Throwing error as POST http://rfg-lt01029:8181/ws/Centrix?wsdl net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Tags: api, web-services, soap, wsdl, blueprism

I'm trying to call SOAP API (which is of Blue prism local) from Web. Its is always throwing `http://rfg-lt01029:8181/ws/Centrix?wsdl net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`.  This WSDL is to start a process in blueprism.

following is the code i'm using

````
<html>
<head>
    <title>SOAP JavaScript Client Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function soap() {
        var data = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:blueprism:webservice:centrix\"> <soapenv:Header/>  <soapenv:Body> <urn:Centrix soapenv:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">   <processType xsi:type=\"xsd:decimal\">1</processType>      </urn:Centrix>  </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if(this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://rfg-lt01029:8181/ws/Centrix?wsdl");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic <password>");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

xhr.send(data);
console.log('next req');
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open('POST', ' http://rfg-lt01029:8181/ws/Centrix?wsdl', true);
            //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('username' + ":" + 'password'));

            // build SOAP request
            var sr =
                '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:blueprism:webservice:centrix">'+
                    '<soapenv:Header/> '+
                    '<soapenv:Body> '+
                        '<urn:Centrix soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> '+
                            '<processType xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1</processType> '+
                        '</urn:Centrix> '+
                    '</soapenv:Body> '+
                "</soapenv:Envelope>" ;
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        // alert('done. use firebug/console to see network response');
                    }
                }
            }
            // Send the POST request
            //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
            xmlhttp.send('');
            // send request
            // ...
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="Demo" action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Soap" onclick="soap();" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html> <!-- typo -->```
````

Answer (score 0):

You would not have exposed the blue prism process as a web service in system tab. That might be creating problem.